# How not to load all images on a page on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

I have a page with a list of jpg images on the page. The div that contains images is hidden and works as images source for Galleria jQuery image gallery plugin. So, when I load a page, it takes long to load it because it loads all images. Is there a way not to load all these images on page load, but just when galleria needs them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load a JSON array of images instead of putting them in the source code:

```
var data = [
    {
        image: 'img1.jpg',
        thumb: 'thumb1.jpg',
        title: 'my first image',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum caption',
        link: 'http://domain.com'
    },
    {
        image: 'img2.jpg',
        thumb: 'thumb2.jpg',
        title: 'my second image',
        description: 'Another caption',
        link: '/path/to/destination.html'
    }
];

$('#container').galleria({
    dataSource: data
});
```

You can also add custom thumbnails:

```
<a href="big.jpg"><img src="thumb.jpg"></a>
```

Galleria recognizes both ways as valid data sources.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether and how it will be able to cooperate with your Gallery plugin, but there is a [Lazy Loading plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) for jQuery. It loads images when they enter the viewport. Maybe worth a look.

Other than that, you would have to tweak the gallery plugin to load the images contained when it shows the div. One idea would be to give all the images a `src` property pointing to a 1x1 transparent GIF:

```
<div class="hidden">
 <img id="image1" src="http://domain.com/images/1x1.gif">
</div>
```

and to keep a JavaScript array with the real image sources:

```
<script>
ImageSources = new Array();
ImageSources[1] = "http://domain.com/images/big_fat_image.jpg";
...
</script>
```

and to assign the real `src` property the moment the `div` gets shown.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, depending on how you load Galleria you have several options..

If you load it via js, you can load the js in a dynamic way, same way Google Analytics loads it's js:

```
 (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

(of course, change the address of the js loads)

Alternative solution, to save the round trip of the js (especially if it's coming from another source and it's parallel), don't call `.loadTheme` before the images are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The demo page of [jQuery image lazy load plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) doesn't seem to work to me on FF3.6 on Mac. I was watching the HTTP requests with the Net tab of Firebug and I could see all the images loaded onload.

Maybe it's worth it to check out this plugin called [JAIL](http://www.sebarmeli.com/projects/jail) that loads only images visible in the viewport.

Your HTML can look like:

```
<img name="/global/images/sample1.jpg" src="/global/images/blank.gif" width="width" height="height"/>
```

and the JS

```
$('img').asynchImageLoader();
```